# google reject apps use sms permissions

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, sms, android-permissions

I want to publish an SMS forwarder app in the Google Play Store but rejected several times. google permitted use for SMS permission documented in this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10208820?visit_id=638320367743206642-844692561&rd=1#intended&zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-sms-and-call-log-permissions), are the following:

- Default SMS handler

  Example of permitted use:
  A user relies on a default SMS app to receive and send SMS messages.

or

- Default Assistant handler

  Example of permitted use: **A user uses this app to receive, translate, and reply to SMS conversations in real-time in someone else’s native language.**

I published my app as the default SMS handler but was rejected and I think, permitted use (based on Google documentation) must be Default Assistant handler. but I didn't find anything about how to be a default assistant handler in Android developer documentation.

What should I do?

Thanks.